# How to display data from another .js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to display user login info onto a React Material UI Typography label that is nested into an App bar(Header.js) by using data from another .js file(Login.js).

Here is the relevant code from the Header.js file:

```
<Typography color='textSecondary' className={classes.userText}>{}</Typography>  // The label for the user info
```

and here is the data to be fetched from the Login.js file:

```
const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

const handleChange = (e) => {
    updateFormData({
        ...formData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
    });
};
const [error, setError] = useState();
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);

    axiosInstance
        .post(`token/`, {
            email: formData.email, //the data I want to be displayed on the App Bar
            password: formData.password,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh);
            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token');
            history.push('/');
            //console.log(res);
            //console.log(res.data);
        
        }, reason =>{
            console.error(reason);
            setError("Invalid login details!")
            alert("Login Failed!\nIncorrect login details!");
        });

};
```

I am expecting to see the user email and display it in the Typography label...

Comment: Ok, update = I created a LoginContext file with the code 
`import React, { createContext } from "react";
export const LoginContext = React.createContext();
`

and I am using `useContext` to read whatever values stored in `createContext` above but I don't know how to pass in values into this `React.createContext();` part so that the other file will be able to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass data from one component to another, and you really have 2 options here(excluding props drilling).
either you pass data using React's ContextAPI, which is easier assuming you are a newbie, or you can use Redux. There is not much to go from your code so you have to read docs here

contextApi: https://refine.dev/blog/usecontext-and-react-context/

redux: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react

Comment: Yes, I am a newbie to React.js lol

Comment: in that case, use contextAPI

Comment: so how can I pass the const formData into the Header.js file using useContext?

Comment: read the docs first,  if you cant figure it out, write what is it exactly

Comment: ok well now I can't figure it out really lol... the user data gets logged into the console.log function that I can see when a user signs in but then how do I display it on the Typography label?

Comment: you have to wrap your whole app inside of context provider. first you create a email context in different component and export it, like ``` export const EmailContext = createContext({})```  . after that, you have to wrap your entire app inside of this context, so its probably best idea to wrap it in your app.js 

import {EmailContext} from '../src/components/Contexts/Context'

const [email,setEmail] = useState('')

return (
<SearchContext.Provider value={{search, setSearch , language, setLanguage}}>
     <AnimatedRoutes/> //(your routes here)
   </SearchContext.Provider>
)

Comment: and in whichever component you have to use this email, import like this

const {email} = useContext(EmailContext)

<Typography color='textSecondary' className={classes.userText}>{email}</Typography>  // The label for the user info

Comment: oh, instead of Search and setSearch, it should be email, setEmail and instead of SearchContext.provider, it should be EmailContext.providet